# Insert a row for each user mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi   I have   an array like the following but with 100 users.

```
$persons = array("rick", "tom", "harry");
```

I have a mysql table  called  mygamestats

```
Id  Person  points  date
 1  john     200    2017/05/01
```

I have a following insert statement

```
$points="200";
$date="2017/06/01";

$sql="INSERT INTO mygamestats (Person,points,date)VALUES ('$person','$points','$date')";
```

How can I  insert into mygamestats table  for each person in my persons array

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mygamestats (Person,points,date)VALUES ('$person','200','2017/06/01')";
```

My final output i trying to achieve is  except its for 100's of users.

```
 Id  Person  points  date
 1  john     200    2017/05/01
 2  rick     200    2017/06/01
 3  tom      200    2017/06/01
 4  harry    200    2017/06/01
```

I read about batch insert or just using foreach key value loop any help much appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach loop to concatenate the insert values:

```
<?php
$persons = array("rick", "tom", "harry");
$points="200";
$date="2017/06/01";

foreach($persons as $person){
    $values[] = "('".$person."','".$points."','".$date."')";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO mygamestats (person,points,date) VALUES ".implode(",",$values);

var_dump($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop on your array and do it in the following way:

```
$points="200";
$date="2017/06/01";
$persons = array("rick", "tom", "harry");

foreach ($persons as $value) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO mygamestats (Person,points,date) VALUES ('$value','$points','$date')"; 
    //Now execute the above query
}
```

Comment: The least you can do is to point the OP to the correct direction

Comment: This will do one query per person which is less efficient (slower) than combining many insert values into a single statement as demonstrated by my answer.